# How to terminate another application using c++/c#/vc++ gracefully?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-c++, process

I have an application running an infinite loop and performing some important functions in that loop. I need to provide the user with another application which would terminate the application with infinite loop. The problem is what if the user terminates the application when it is inside loop performing some operation. It would lead to inconsistent state. I tried kill() and TerminateProcess but they didn't help. Is there any way I could signal the application with infinite loop that complete your iteration and exit? I am open to solutions in c#,cpp and vc++.

EDIT:

The source code for looping program is accessible.

Comment: There is no need for an extra application to do that.

Comment: Its my requirement to have an extra application to do that. The infinite loop application would be running in background and should be stopped when the user wants. Why do u guys jump to conclusions so fast??

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without clear details. Based on your comment, look into listening on a port in the background process.

Comment: Without changing the looping program the answer is no.  Please update the question if you can make changes to the looping program.

Comment: Yes, the source code to the looping program is accessible

Comment: Add a termination flag. Test the termination flag inside the loop and exit if set. Define a protocol by which the second program can set the termination flag.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, the generic term is Inter-Process Communication.  Possible ways are:  Using the existence of a file as a flag; shared memory; sockets; cross process semaphores/mutexes (not the C++ std::mutex) ... etc.  Set the flag in one process; test and if set clear it and perform your action in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are many variations on Interprocess Communication, for this purpose a simple event will suffice.

In the process you need to control:

- `hEvent = CreateEvent()` (with a name, make it sufficiently unique)
- Periodically check it with `WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, ZERO_TIMEOUT)`

From the process to do the controlling:

- `hEvent = OpenEvent()` passing the same name
- `SetEvent(hEvent)` will cause the return value from `WaitForSingleObject` in the other process to change.

A slightly nicer way might be to start a background thread in the main application which creates a window and a taskbar icon with an Exit option on its menu.  Then you only need to share an event between threads, not between processes, which removes the requirement for a unique name.

Comment: A side benefit of using a window is that your process can exit gracefully when killed via taskkill.exe. Just handle the `WM_CLOSE` message. Annoyingly, "end task" in the GUI Task Manager only works like this when the window is visible. Otherwise it forcefully terminates the process.

Answer (score 1):

> an application running an infinite loop and performing some important functions

As long as it does "important functions", the program in question has a way to obtain new input data from somewhere (e.g., from a file or from a network socket). Therefore, you can add a special token into input data with a meaning "end of operation". Upon receiving such token, the program will know that it is time to shut itself down. One of the simplest tokens of such nature are end-of-file for regular files or remote side socket closure.

The method I just described is simple and is what may be called "in-band control channel". That is, you use a single channel to both feed data to process and commands to control (even if there is just one command, "stop").

An alternative to that would be "out of band control channel", that is, a second channel to pass commands between applications.

> The problem is what if the user terminates the application when it is inside loop performing some operation. It would lead to inconsistent state.

Your attempts to use `kill` is one possibility to use facilities known as inter-process [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)). To use it properly, the receiving program must register a signal handler routine to initiate a shutdown on its own. The sender should use a matching signal number. Using `kill` (SIGKILL in POSIX) is not the best choice because it has a special behavior and cannot be assigned with a custom signal handler. In POSIX, it is better to use SIGUSR1 or one of many other signals. I do not remember native Windows equivalents for that.

There is a multitude of mechanisms to organize an inter-processor communication between processes in a conventional operating system, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to a full list for everything from a shared file to named pipes and network sockets. Choose one that suites your needs best. You only need to pass a single bit of data, so basically the one that is the easiest to program is the best.

Comment: In Windows, Task Manager and taskkill.exe gracefully end a task by posting `WM_CLOSE` to its windows. Task Manager only uses visible windows, but taskkill.exe also works with invisible windows.  Background tasks can also be implemented as a service, which can be controlled from the command line via net.exe or sc.exe, or using the system management console's services.msc snap-in.